# Central locking doesn't work, alarm goes off when getting into car, won't start

Tags: electrical, renault, alarm, immobilizer, clio

I have a Renaultsport Clio 182 which has been off the road for a while and the battery drained very low

When I tried to get into the car to start it, it would not start and the alarm went off. I also could not use the key fob to unlock the central locking remotely (but the red light on the fob flashed when I pressed the key). Also, when I turned the key in the passenger door to lock it, the drivers door did not lock either

I opened the bonnet and held down the sensor to stop the alarm, and then I replaced the car battery. The car would not start and the alarm went off when I got in. Remote central locking still would not work

I have now got some new CR1220 batteries for the key fob. I am going to replace this tonight and try again.

Am I doing anything wrong? It feels odd that the remote central locking doesn't work even though the car battery is full - and it feels even odder that the central locking doesn't work when I physically lock the passengers door

Comment: You put a different battery in the car, but are you completely sure it is fully charged?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes I used a multimeter to check the battery, 12 hours before I put it in and then immediately before I put it in, both read just under 13 volts

Comment: Good deal and sounds about right. I'd suggest there's an issue with the body control module (or whatever part on your car controls the alarm system). I couldn't tell you exactly what is wrong with it, but it seems likely.